# Bluemix issue : Can't see any files in a Cloud Foundry Apps

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I use Bluemix.net to access a Cloud Foundry Apps which has been created by another user who gave me access to his organization. We created a web page and we both need to update html files and deploy the new web page.

The issue is that I can't view any files in the editor to make updates :

Here is what I see
[image: Here is what I see]

Here is what I should see
[image: Here is what I should see]

The creator gave me access to his organization with the Manager, Billing Manager and Auditor roles.

Could you help me to fix it ?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: This seems like an IBM-internal system. Are you sure this is a public question?

Comment: data_henrik - it could easily be a public system. IBM hosts a cloud foundry infrastructure.

Comment: made images visible

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the down arrow to expand and see the files.

[image: arrow]